# About the integral form of a quantum group

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

As far as I understood, in order to specialize a quantum group $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$, lets say over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$, to an element $\epsilon \in \mathbb{C}^\times$, it is necessary to find a $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$-subalgebra $U \subseteq U_q(\mathfrak{g})$, s.t. $U \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]} \mathbb{Q}(q) \cong U_q(\mathfrak{g})$. The specialization is then defined as $U \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]} \mathbb{C}_\epsilon$ (where $q.1=\epsilon$ in $\mathbb{C}_\epsilon$).

I have two (rather naive) questions: 1. Why do we take a $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$-subalgebra and not for example a $\mathbb{Q}[q,q^{-1}]$-subalgebra, s.t. $U\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}[q,q^{-1}]}\mathbb{Q}(q) \cong U_q(\mathfrak{g})$? 2. I would expect a specialization to be an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, but the above is still an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$, so there is still a formal parameter $q$ left (which behaves much nicer, but still..)

Comment: 1. Because that's the smallest base ring you can get away with.  If you want $\mathbb{Q}$, then just tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$.  2. I have no idea what you mean. The specialization is most naturally an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$; it's true that it's still a $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$, but no one would think about it that way (in particular, it's not a finitely generated algebra over $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$).